# Finding an error in app.yaml or .yaml file

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

When I'm trying to deploy the latest version of my app to GAE, it's giving me an error. What I have read is that somewhere I might be using Tabs instead of spaces, but I have no clue where? How can I find the location of the error through the log?

```
2014-10-26 21:58:46 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files    (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=email@gmail.com', '-- passin', '--server=clever-app.appspot.com', 'update', 'D:\\Documents\\app-spot Project\\wp39 - Copy']"
09:58 PM Application: clever-app; version: wpfromstarterproject-10262014
09:58 PM Host: clever-app.appspot.com

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
run_file(__file__, globals())
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5400, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5391, in main
result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2981, in Run
self.action(self)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5047, in __call__
return method()
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3794, in Update
self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3815, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
updatecheck.CheckForUpdates()
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\sdk_update_checker.py", line 243, in CheckForUpdates
runtime=runtime))
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib\yaml\__init__.py", line 82, in safe_load
return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib\yaml\__init__.py", line 66, in load
return loader.get_data()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib\yaml\constructor.py", line 38, in get_data
return self.construct_document(self.get_node())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib\yaml\composer.py", line 27, in get_node
return self.compose_document()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib\yaml\composer.py", line 37, in compose_document
self.get_event()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib\yaml\parser.py", line 115, in get_event
self.current_event = self.state()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib\yaml\parser.py", line 190, in parse_document_end
token = self.peek_token()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib\yaml\scanner.py", line 128, in peek_token
self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib\yaml\scanner.py", line 257, in fetch_more_tokens
% ch.encode('utf-8'), self.get_mark())

yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
in "<string>", line 4, column 1:
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
^
2014-10-26 21:58:52 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

I've pasted my app.yaml file here as requested: http://pastebin.com/geLGNKCY

Comment: The error message says: line 4, column 1.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Well this is where I'm kind of embarrassed - line 4 column 1 of which file? The last file in the log? There were about 20 files in the log would I have to check each one? I'll update with the full log.

Comment: Can you paste your app.yaml contents? From the error message, it looks like it is trying to parse an html-ish file as yaml. Unless the sdk update checker pulls down a yaml file and that part is failing with an html document...

Comment: I've included my app.yaml file: http://pastebin.com/geLGNKCY also when I visit the /api/updatecheck URL I get the following: release: "1.9.14" timestamp: 1412902384 api_versions: ['1'] supported_api_versions: python: api_versions: ['1'] python27: api_versions: ['1'] go: api_versions: ['go1'] java7: api_versions: ['1.0']

Answer (score 1):

Wait a minute.  This is all sorts of weirdness then.  I apologize that I didn't read through your error stack trace more closely.

Your error trace indicates that things are going wrong around here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/sdk_update_checker.py#235

But this is checking for an SDK update.  This should not fail.  Very strange!

Can you try with and without the `--skip_sdk_update_check` flag to your call to appcfg.py, and confirm that what you're seeing is an error during the SDK check?

Is the error repeatable?

Also, from your machine, can you show us what you see if you visit http://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?  Do you happen to have some web proxy or firewall of some sort?  I'm admittedly speculating on what could possibly do this, as I don't understand the error yet.  (The error message suggests that somehow you're getting HTML content in a very unexpected place, so something is odd.)

Comment: No worries! Appreciate the help with this repeatable error. I did try adding the --skip_sdk_update_check flag in the GAE launcher but got the same issue. Also when I visit the /api/updatecheck link I get the following:     release: "1.9.14" timestamp: 1412902384 api_versions: ['1'] supported_api_versions: python: api_versions: ['1'] python27: api_versions: ['1'] go: api_versions: ['go1'] java7: api_versions: ['1.0']

Comment: I'm still very confused.  :(  You should not be getting the same exact issue, because that code path should be skipped entirely when you use `--skip_sdk_update_check`.  Please double-check that you're getting the exact same stack trace in your logs, and that you're not looking at outdated logs.

Comment: (All of this being done in the GAE Launcher) - so I was trying to Deploy before hitting Run! Now I added the flag, hit Run and I get an error. [The entire log is here](http://pastebin.com/19jDmXpG) and the last lines being:  `File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\boolean_action.py", line 78, in BooleanParse
    (values, ', '.join(repr_values)))
    ValueError: 'D:\\Documents\\Clever-app Project\\wp39 - Copy'     unrecognized boolean; known booleans are 'true', 'yes', '1',     'false', 'no', '0'.
    2014-10-27 18:18:04 (Process exited with code 1)`

Comment: Whoops.  The flag `--skip_sdk_update_check` is a boolean flag.  In absence of the flag value, the flag parser is trying to interpret your **project directory** as the boolean flag value, which is definitely not intended.  We've got to say: `--skip_sdk_update_check=yes`.

Comment: Well now.. that only works for Local: `2014-10-27 21:57:31 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8081', '--admin_port=8000', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', 'D:\\Documents\\app Project\\wp39 - Copy']"` App Deploy: `2014-10-27 22:06:43 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=myemail', '--passin', u'--server=173.194.104.82', 'update', 'D:\\Documents\\app Project\\wp39 - Copy']"`